# Skype sometimes crashing whole system

Tags: windows-10, skype, bug

I suffered this thing already twice in this weeek. It looks like this: I'm calling someone through voice only Skype call, at the moment my call answered - my PC starts to produce distructing repeating noise and only hard reboot (with power button can help this issue).

Most of the times Skype calls going well with no complains.

As it was the only reason to crash I observed so far, I suspect that Skype has a bad bug inside.

Any other thoughts?

PS. OS Windows 10, PC - Lenovo IdeaPad 5 14ARE05 with Ryzen 7 4700U

Comment: Skype has a lot of bugs, and they probable won't be all fixed, since so far Skype is suppose to fade out (Teams will be the replacement). DId you check the events yet?

Comment: @Albin which events are you talking about? Could you specify where can I check it out?

Comment: run `eventvwr.msc`, there are various hints on errors, crashes, etc.

Comment: This could also be a problem with audio drivers - I'd suggest updating Skype and any audio drivers installed.

Comment: I’d suggest Win8 which is much faster.  Watch for the hundreds of scheduled maintenance tasks and backup task